# Insert 0 to 999999 rows in a table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have written following simple procedure in mysql to run insert statement 1,000,000 times.

```
 DELIMITER $$
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS INIT_DEGREE_PRECISION$$
 CREATE PROCEDURE INIT_DEGREE_PRECISION()
       BEGIN
               DECLARE x  INT;
               DECLARE zeros  VARCHAR(8);
               DELETE FROM degree_precision;
               SET x = 1;
               WHILE x  <= 999999 DO
                           insert into degree_precision (degree_precision_id) values (x);
                           SET  x = x + 1;
               END WHILE;
       END$$
 DELIMITER ;
```

But when I am calling this procedure it is taking too much time on my local machine. I am supposed to run this on remote server. Is there any better way of doing this?

**What I am trying to do?**

I have a table that contain only one column `degree_precision_id` in table `degree_precision`. This table will have only 1,000,000 no of rows with degree_precision_id values `0 - 999999`. To do this I have written a procedure but it takes hell lot of time.

Comment: Build `INSERT INTO tab VALUES(),(), (), (), (), ...` in batches with 10k rows per statement.

Comment: i will show a real fast way, if no one else does, in a few minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a `cross join`:

```
insert into degree_precision (degree_precision_id)
    select (@rn := @rn + 1) - 1 as rn
    from (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) d1 cross join 
         (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) d2 cross join 
         (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) d3 cross join 
         (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) d4 cross join 
         (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) d5 cross join 
         (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) d6 cross join
         (select @rn := 0) params
```

Note that `create table as` is probably faster, because of logging overhead.

Answer (score 1):

nothing beats this for speed in my book (my book is small though)

```
drop table myTable7;
create table myTable7
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    blah int not null
)engine=myISAM;  -- <---- chosen for speed, and no-gaps, read comments below

insert myTable7(blah) values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1);
insert myTable7(blah) select blah from myTable7;
insert myTable7(blah) select blah from myTable7;
insert myTable7(blah) select blah from myTable7;
insert myTable7(blah) select blah from myTable7;
insert myTable7(blah) select blah from myTable7;
insert myTable7(blah) select blah from myTable7;
insert myTable7(blah) select blah from myTable7;
insert myTable7(blah) select blah from myTable7;
insert myTable7(blah) select blah from myTable7;
insert myTable7(blah) select blah from myTable7;
insert myTable7(blah) select blah from myTable7;
insert myTable7(blah) select blah from myTable7;
insert myTable7(blah) select blah from myTable7;
insert myTable7(blah) select blah from myTable7;
insert myTable7(blah) select blah from myTable7;
insert myTable7(blah) select blah from myTable7;
insert myTable7(blah) select blah from myTable7;    -- 1.3M rows

-- total time 2.1 seconds

select count(*),min(id),max(id) from myTable7;
delete from myTable7 where id>1000000;  -- 1.1 secs
select count(*),min(id),max(id) from myTable7;  -- 1 M rows

then on to ALTER TABLE to reset auto inc if necessary
```

### Edit

Concerning N.B.'s comment below, refer to this fine [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17434) and a quote, and looking at my speed comparisons and try your own

> Thus, in a heavy-read environment, it is possible for a MyISAM table
>   with a Fixed Row Format to outperform InnoDB reads out of the InnoDB
>   Buffer Pool if there is enough data being written into the undo logs
>   contained within ibdata1 to support the transactional behavior imposed
>   on the InnoDB data.

So clearly (to me), INNODB gets bogged down by the undo logs / "transactional behavior"

Comment: sorry, i did a poor job of documenting it. Basically, each insert after the (1),(1), etc line inserts a new row based on all the rows that are already there. So it grows fast.

Comment: ok, but in my case I want primary key to have values of blah. I can tweak that by changing primary key to blah later.

Comment: I went with `myISAM` to ensure no-gaps in the id's, as INNODB will give the right row count but create islands of id gaps. Plus INNODB is like 10 times slower. This above Answer is useful for quick bulk inserts for such things as doing left joins (such as, which account id's don't exist anymore), and for optimal speed. So `MyIsam` wasn't chosen by accident

Comment: `MyISAM` is slower than `InnoDB` and has been for a long, long while. Insertion speed is **always** achieved by finding the sweet spot between HDD's I/O and bandwith capabilities. A 1m insert on InnoDB and mediocre hdd can take up as little as a few seconds. In MyISAM's case, it's the OS that schedules the writes (and this optimizes what you are able to do on your own with InnoDB). It's also the reason why MyISAM is famous for losing records. Please mention all the facts before categorically stating something.

Comment: Let us know your test results @N.B. Mine are at 2 seconds for MyISAM and 20 for INNODB. My point was primarily one of gaps, for not choosing INNODB

Comment: You can have your *opinion* and you're entitled to that. I also realize you're trying to help. However, consider what happens when someone who is less versed in the world of MySQL stumbles upon your answer and concludes that a person with 8k+ rep said that "MyISAM is faster". In the scope of the question asked it's absolutely silly to suggest MyISAM and justify it with botched-up test you've made. ID gaps as you called them - so what? Want nice numbers - create another column and use 1 process to update them 0 - 99999999, job done.

Comment: @N.B. the quote from the OP was `when I am calling this procedure it is taking too much time on my local machine.`  And we both know INNODB has transactional and undo log overhead that makes it slow. I am not suggesting that MyISAM should be used for every table or in general. But the facts remain it is faster for this approach, much faster, gap-less, which you do not refute. You had a problem answering a question I posed to you a month or two ago when you went after one of my Answers or in a comment back and forth and got nasty and flagged there. Let's not revisit those screen shots