# SQL to detect "sequence break"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data in which incremental sequence is broken somewhere, maybe multiple times.
E.g. (2,3,4,5,6,8,10).

I want to get:

1. the first "broken" place (6 is the last good in the example)
2. the number of "broken" places (2 times, on 7 and 9)

using SQL (preferably general, which works on oracle and mysql and other sql platforms).

Using sequences or auto_increment are platform-specific.

I tried self-join constructions like

```
select curr.id+1 as first_fail from junk as prev
join junk as curr 
on (prev.id+1 = curr.id) 
order by curr.id desc limit 1;
```

(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bae781/4/0)
but it seems ugly, and can't get the number of "broken" places this way.

Comment: Probably `gaps and islands` problem

Comment: If you join the table to itself on y = x + 1, how many null results do you get?

Comment: @Andrey Regentov: Check the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All beginning "breaks" sorted by ids:

```sql
select j1.id + 1 as id
from junk j1
left join junk j2 on j2.id = j1.id + 1
where j2.id is null
    and j1.id <> (select max(id) from junk)
order by j1.id;
```

Pick the first row to get the first "break". Count number of rows to get the number of "breaks".

If you need the number of all missing ids:

```sql
-- get number of missing ids
select 
    -- num rows you should have
    (select max(id) from junk) - (select min(id) from junk)     + 1
    -- num rows you really have
    - count(*) as num_missings
from junk;
```

Or shorter:

```sql
select max(id) - min(id) + 1 - count(*) as num_missings from junk;
```

Comment: Although other answers works too, accepting this because it is the only that works in non-mysql (namely, oracle) without alterations.

Answer (score 3):

Check this :

```
select prev_id+1 as first_fail,count(*)-1 as total_broken from
(
   select curr.id as curr_id,prev.id as prev_id
   from junk as prev
   left join junk as curr  on prev.id+1 = curr.id
) sub where sub.curr_id is null ;
```

SQL Fiddle Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bae781/62

Query If Gap is wider than 1

```
select p2_id-1 as first_fail,sum(broken) as total_broken from
(select p1.row_num as p1_row,p2.row_num as p2_row,p1.id as p1_id,p2.id as p2_id,(p2.id-p1.id-1) as broken from
( 
  select @row_num:=@row_num+1 as row_num,junk.id
  from junk,(select @row_num:=0) s1
) p1
left join
( 
  select @row_num2:=@row_num2+1 as row_num,junk.id
  from junk,(select @row_num2:=0) s2
) p2 on p1.row_num+1=p2.row_num ) as sub
where broken is not null and broken > 0;
```

SQL Fiddle Demo:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/974ec/1

Comment: It won't work when gap is wider than 1 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba44e/1/0, but if OP wants gaps only number it is ok

Comment: @lad2025: check the updated one. It works when gap is wider than 1 also.

Comment: Someone has down voted  my answer but it's a correct solution.

Comment: Looks ok, I don't know who downvoted you but from me +1

Answer (score 2):

You can generate tally table and use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT  MIN(SeqValue)-1 AS `first`, COUNT(*) AS `total`
FROM (
  SELECT
    (TWO_1.SeqValue + TWO_2.SeqValue + TWO_4.SeqValue + TWO_8.SeqValue + TWO_16.SeqValue) SeqValue
   FROM
    (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 1 SeqValue) TWO_1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 2 SeqValue) TWO_2
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 4 SeqValue) TWO_4
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 8 SeqValue) TWO_8
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 SeqValue UNION ALL SELECT 16 SeqValue) TWO_16
)  AS tally
LEFT JOIN  junk
ON junk.id = tally.SeqValue
WHERE tally.SeqValue >= (SELECT MIN(id) FROM junk)
 AND tally.SeqValue <= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM junk)
 AND junk.id IS NULL;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bae781/47/0)**</kbd>

There is plenty of ways to generate tally table (`CTE/recursive CTE/subquery/table function/variables/windowed function`).

You can easily interchange tally subquery (my example provides only limited range).

**EDIT:**

One way to extend it quickly for `MySQL` is to [`use multiple CROSS JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189100/insert-0-to-999999-rows-in-a-table-in-mysql):

```
SELECT  MIN(SeqValue)-1 AS `first`, COUNT(*) AS `total`
FROM (select (@rn := @rn + 1) - 1 as SeqValue
      from (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) d1 cross join 
         (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) d2 cross join 
         (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) d3 cross join 
         (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) d4 cross join 
         (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) d5 cross join 
         (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) d6 cross join
         (select @rn := 0) params
)  AS tally
LEFT JOIN  junk
ON junk.id = tally.SeqValue
WHERE tally.SeqValue >= (SELECT MIN(id) FROM junk)
 AND tally.SeqValue <= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM junk)
 AND junk.id IS NULL;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bae781/73/0)**</kbd>

Comment: Note: this query is limited by `max id=31`, you should add `cross joins` to get more

Comment: @vp_arth Yes I know it. The point is I don't want to starting discussion which method is better for generating tally table. I've added quick replacement up to 1 milion.

Answer (score 1):

This is looking for how many id's skipped before, and what was last correct:

```
SET @i:=0, @last:=0;
SELECT id, skipped_before, last_correct FROM (
    SELECT id, 
           @i:=@i+1 row_num, 
           id-@i-1 skipped_before, 
           if(id-@i=1,@last:=id,@i:=@i+id-@last-1), 
           @last last_correct
    FROM junk
) a
WHERE skipped_before;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7fa577/7)

---

Broken chains count is row with `skipped_berore>0` count.
`First fail` is obviously minimal `last_correct+1`.
Missed ids count is `sum(skipped_before)`,
  but this can be found easier with

```
SELECT MAX(id)-MIN(id)-COUNT(id)+1 FROM junk;
```